# Mongo aggregate search results based on unique subcollection property with count?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to do this for many hours now, I have a collection called 'Jobs' -- inside, they have a subcollection 'Site' which is Jobs.site. This Site subcollection has the property 'UNID'.

I'm trying to retreive documents from the database based on a text search, that works fine.

But I'm trying to retreive only UNIQUE documents based on that Job.Site.UNID and perhaps have a count added as an extra property. The result should look like:

`Job: { site: { field1: 'EXAMPLE', UNID: 'SITEID', count: 5  } }`

Which would mean there are 5 jobs inside the job collection that have that site.UNID.

This is what I have so far:

```
[
// GETTING DOCS BASED ON TEXT SEARCH RESULTS
    {
      $match: {
        // clientId: req.user.client_id,
        $text: { $search: body.searchTerms }
      }
    },
// SORTING THEM BASED ON TEXTSCORE
    { $sort: { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } },
// THE PROBLEMATIC GROUPING PART
    { $group: { site: { UPRN: '$UPRN', myCount: { $sum: 1 } } } },
// I ONYL WANT TO GET 20 DOCS AT A TIME
    { $limit: 20 },
// THE DATA THAT I WANT IN MY DOCUMENTS, MAYBE COUNT WOULD COME HERE?
    {
      $project: {
        site: true,
        score: { $meta: 'textScore' }
      }
    },
// GETTING RID OF POOR MATCHES BASED ON A SCORE CALCULATED IN ANOTHER 
// FUNCTION BASED ON THE NUMBER OF WORDS IN THE TEXT SEARCH
    {
      $match: {
        score: { $gt: matchScore }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Here it hits me with `The field 'site' must be an accumulator object`

So I can't figure out the syntax to properly work on that subcollection property.

EDIT: V2 thanks to @Anthony work perfectly and have tested it thoroughly except it doesn't seem to count the total number of jobs, it's always 1 or whatever I set in $sum:  but there's 200+ results, still working on it.

```
 { $match: { $text: { $search: body.searchTerms } } },
    { $sort: { $score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } },
    // { $match: { score: { $gt: 0.1 } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$UNID',
        counter: { $sum: 1 },
        score: { $first: { $meta: 'textScore' } },
        title: { $first: '$title' },
        postcode: { $first: '$postcode' },
        addressLine1: { $first: '$addressLine1' },
        city: { $first: '$city' },
        projectName: { $first: '$projectName' },
        jobsCount: { $sum: '$counter' }
      }
    },
    { $limit: 20 },
    {
      $project: {
        UNID: '$_id',
        title: '$title',
        postcode: '$postcode',
        addressLine1: '$addressLine1',
        projectName: '$projectName',
        city: '$city',
        score: 1,
        jobsCount: true
      }
    }
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
{
  "_id": "randomString0",
  "title": "Quality",
  "site": {
    "_id": "rKFRbvH8CEbJYdzDs",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "UNID": "001",
    "city": "cityName",
    "createdAt": null
  }
},
{
  "_id": "randomString1",
  "title": "Some2123",
  "site": {
    "_id": "rKFRbvH8CEbJYdzDs",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "UNID": "001",
    "city": "cityName",
    "createdAt": null
  }
},
{
  "_id": "randomString2",
  "title": "Random title",
  "site": {
    "_id": "rKFRbvH8CEbJYdzDs",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "UNID": "001",
    "city": "cityName",
    "createdAt": null
  }
},
{
  "_id": "randomString3",
  "title": "Another unique job",
  "site": {
    "_id": "rKFRbvH8CEbJYdzDs",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "UNID": "001",
    "city": "cityName",
    "createdAt": null
  }
},
{
  "_id": "randomString4",
  "title": "Other thing",
  "site": {
    "_id": "rKFRbvH8CEbJYdzDs",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "UNID": "001",
    "city": "cityName",
    "createdAt": null
  }
},
{
  "_id": "randomString5",
  "title": "Something else",
  "site": {
    "_id": "rKFRbvH8CEbJYdzDs",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "UNID": "001",
    "city": "cityName",
    "createdAt": null
  }
}
```

As you can see, the site data will always be unique under all those 5 documents, but the counter should count how many docs have the same unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage the `_id`(to which you want to group by) expression is the required expression. And there are only few [**`accumulators`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator) you can use with the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation stage.

So your aggregation must be something like this

```
[
  { "$match": { "$text": { "$search": body.searchTerms }}},
  { "$sort": { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
  { "$match": { "score": { "$gt": matchScore }}},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$UPRN",
    "myCount": { "$sum": 1 },
    "score": { "$first": "$score" }
  }},
  { "$limit": 20 },
  { "$project": {
    "site": "$_id",
    "score": 1,
    "myCount": 1
  }}
]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @Anthony -- really broke me out of the gridlock. -- I've been trying things out with it and looking at the data since the moment you posted the answer! -- Currently though, under $project doesn't return the site data even if I type site: true as I had before and score seems to be null always -- will continue trying things out, thanks!

Comment: Also -- having it distinct does work but the count currently does not count the number of jobs -- it just defaults to 1 regardless of how I project things under "myCount" hmmm

Comment: Could you post some sample collection. I Will show you the exact output then.

Comment: Everything works now! I'm getting the data and I'm only getting the unique stuff, however the count $sum doesn't seem to work. I'm also running a total counts for said UNID and I see/know there's 200+ documents that all have the same UNID, I only get the 2 with the sites data which is exactly what I wanted but it doesn't count them, it always returns 1 or whatever I set in $sum: 1

Comment: Try to remove second match stage. I think there your data is being blocked

Comment: Ah, yeah! I have done that the very first thing as I could see there were results from my parallel aggregation but none showed up to this, but even so the $sum aggregation doesn't seem to work yet, I have updated my post with the modified code that works great thanks to you. Just this one last bit to figure out! Thanks again!

Comment: Use `counter: 11 in the `$project` stage.  Nothing much

Comment: Doesn't do anything sadly :( still displays just 1. I've still been trying to wrap my head around the $sum operator and how its logic works in this context.

Comment: I have added to my post both the updated query that works ok up until the counter and a sample data with 5 documents.

Comment: Just copied actual full documents over and tested it in that sandbox and everything works..., then copied the exact same aggregation, without the $match and everything and all my UNID/any other data, shows up as 'null'. If I do a text search, myCount will be total results...something is fishy

Comment: May be your checking with wrong database. Which GUI you are using?

Comment: I swear something is really weird, so I'm running in parallel for every text search another one that just counts total matches for that search term so I know the data is there when the aggregation starts. I'm using Mongoose within node with Typescript... but it just doesn't work, all it returns is null! In the aggregation I added in my initial post -- the data comes out right except for that counter... yet I literally copied the documents from the database (mLab interface) for the demo and everything works inside that demo...There's no more variables I can think to single out :(

Comment: I'll delete this later but here's literally the code currently running live and a screen recording of the 2 results in parallel: https://streamable.com/wc59t ++ https://i.imgur.com/CIuRlrz.png